# A script for upadate textbox's value in asp.net mvc didn' work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to update textbox's value(that contains cookie's value) using Ajax in asp.net MVC5 . I'm very new in JavaScript and I wrote these codes , but my code didn't work . I didn't get any error but it's not working. I wrote JavaScript in foreign file 'UpdateTxtBox.js'  and I added `<script src="~/Scripts/UpdateTxtBox.js"></script>` to Layout .
Could anyone tell me what's the problem ?

```
$(function () {
$("textCountProduct").change(function () {
    var count = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr("productid");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Goods/AddToCart",
        data: { Id: id, Count: count },
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                alert(result.Html);
                $("#CartItems").html(result.Html);
            }
            eval(result.Script);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error....");
        }
    });
});
});
```

a part of **Basket.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Goods", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Count, new { @class="text textCountProduct" , style="width:40px;" , productid=item.GoodDetails.DetailsGoodID})

 }
```

**Good controller**

```
public ActionResult AddToCart (int Id , int Count)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()))
        {
            //Edit cookie
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString(), (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()].Value) + 1).ToString());
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

        }
        else
        {
            //Add new cookie
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString(), Count.ToString());
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
            List<HttpCookie> lst = new List<HttpCookie>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.Count; i++ )
            {
                lst.Add(Request.Cookies[i]);
            }

            bool isGet = Request.HttpMethod == "GET";
            int CartCount = lst.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("NishtmanCart_") && p.HttpOnly != isGet).Count();
            return Json(new MyJsonData()
            {
                Success = true,
                Script = MessageBox.Show("Good added successfully", MessageType.Success).Script,
                //Script = "alert('Good added successfully');",
                Html = "cart items  (" + CartCount.ToString() + ")"
            }
                );
        }
```

Update post :
I added [HttpPost] to controller action result and add some alert to javascript

```
$(function () {
alert("aleeeert");
$(".textCountProduct").change(function () {
    var count = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr("productid");
    alert(count);
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Goods/AddToCart",
        data: { Id: id, Count: count },
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                alert(result.Html);
                $("#CartItems").html(result.Html);
            }
            eval(result.Script);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error....");
        }
    });
});
});
```

it's working fine but when I refresh page , data didn't saved

Comment: you have made mistake here `$("textCountProduct")` use `.` in as `selector`.It should be `$(".textCountProduct")`

Comment: Thank you , I corrected it but it's not working yet @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Please check your browser console. Is ajax calling?

Comment: There is no error in console . It's means ajax called ? @ParthTrivedi

Comment: No in network an ajax request display when change perform.

Comment: I can't see any request in network :/  @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101159/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-shima-amini).

Comment: The controller http verb is ```get``` but ajax type ```post```?

Comment: I added [HttpPost] to controller action but result is the same @dee

Comment: And the value of ```url``` in the ajax call is correct? Did you use ```"@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Goods")"``` to get the url?

Comment: No ! I didn't use it . where should I use it ? for what issue ? please @dee

Comment: In the ajax call get the url like this: ```$.ajax({url: "@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Goods")", ...})```. But wait, the script is in external js-file? Then the url needs to be passed as parameter from the cshtml view.

Comment: I myself wrote `url: "/Goods/AddToCart",`  and tested yours but it didn't work and gave me error  @dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made mistake here `$("textCountProduct")` use `.` as selector.
It should be `$(".textCountProduct")`

and

Check path of your script included

```
<script src="~/Scripts/UpdateTxtBox.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have specified `textCountProduct` as CSS class, you need to prefix it with `.` to use [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), As of now its looking for Element `textCountProduct` which obviously doesn't exists.

*Use*

```
$(".textCountProduct").change(
```

Comment: I updated my post dear , could you please take look at it ?

Comment: @shimaamini, Can you elaborate `data didn't saved`?

Comment: The value of the text box is the same as the cookie, that the action can be changed by this, but when the value is changed, it sometimes gets saved and sometimes not in cookie